# Is there a way to play PVZ 2 Special Events more than once per day?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies-2

PVZ 2 (Plants vs Zombies 2) has a special event every day.  Sometimes I finish it and want to play it again.  But it seems it won't let me play again.  Is there a way?

(I could also hit "Restart" before the last zombie dies, or can create another profile and finish at least Day 1 to Day 6 and also play the special event.  Other than that, are there any other ways?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to, sorry. The daily events are designed to keep you checking back for new content every day. Allowing you to replay them would remove some of the 'specialness' from them.

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago, a patch was released to where you can replay the pinata party once per day after completing it by watching an ad. This means you get double the rewards by beating it twice.

Answer (score -3):

Don't have the game so can't test it but your best bet is to time glitch - move the clock of your device to the next day.

Comment: but then you may play next day's event, if it is already set on the server